# Autofill form from Ajax json data jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to parse returned data from json into form fields via an autocomplete form, I have been able to get the auto complete part working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var autocompleteArray = new Array();

jQuery("#business-name").keyup(function() {

    myVar = jQuery(this).val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<API_URL>',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "<AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN>"); 
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        data: {"q":myVar,"items_per_page":5},
        success: function(data) {
            // Process data here to autofill form input elements with json reponse.

           console.log(autocompleteArray); // View the Array in console

           autocompleteArray.length = 0; // EMPTY ARRAY 

            jQuery(data.items).each(function(index, value) {
      //          console.log(value.title); //entry into json
                autocompleteArray.push(value.title);
            });

            jQuery("#business-name").autocomplete({
                source: autocompleteArray
            });
        },
         error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    console.log('Unable to Establish Connection');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    console.log('Requested Page Not Found [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    console.log('Internal Server Error [500]');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    console.log('Requested JSON Parse Failure');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    console.log('Time Out Error');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    console.log('Ajax Request Aborted');
                } else {
                    console.log('Uncaught Error' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
         }
    });

});

});
```

So when a user types a company name the form offers 5 autocomplete options, what I need to do now is create an on click action for each of the options returned which will grab the data from the database and fill the form.

My problem is where should I insert the autofill code do I need it in the  keyup data success function? And what syntax would work best for me?

Not worked on jQuery for a while so I am struggling at the moment with this one.

This is what I am thinking...

```
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.ui-menu-item', function(){
    var coMpany = jQuery(this).val();
     value.coMpany.address1 // <<<<<<<< push this value to form address1
     value.coMpany.postcode // <<<<<<<< push this value to form postcode
                // and so on and so on
 });
```

(How can I pass (data) to the above and use it to fill the form)

---

I almost have it working with this code my problem is the code logs all select items - I only want to get data for the selected item.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.ui-menu-item', function(){
   jQuery(data.items).each(function(key, value) {
    if (jQuery(".ui-menu-item").val() === value.title) {
  // RUN THIS CODE FOR SELECTED ITEM
          console.log(value.title);
          console.log(value.address.address_line_1);
  // PROBLEM * CODE LOGS ALL ITEMS IN ".ui-menu-item" CLASSES (I ONLY WANT IT TO LOG THE ONE I CLICK ON)
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Avoid adding sensitive data in the future

Comment: The key is locked to my domain @mbharanidharan88

Comment: Ok fine. Still, try to provide just the stub rather than the original one.

Comment: Will do in future thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use like this.

`$(document).on('click', '.what-ever-id-class-the-result-has', function(){
   // codes after clicking
})`

Comment: yes that's what i was thinking but where can I put that code while still having access to the data and also how to grab the value of the object and find it in the data?

Comment: No, I almost have it working though I updated the question.

Comment: I just fixed it by adding a variable outside of the each function

Comment: Thanks for your help